# what tasksel not showing ubunto-desktop

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am running UTA on mac M1 and I am installing ubuntu server 20*, it come into. point where I need to install UI for it, I have upgraded/ updated apt and installed taskesl, I don't know why I can't see the option to chose ubuntu-desktop when I type `tasksel` it shows only this options and when I type `tasksel install ubuntu-desktop it return nothing, also I have installed` sudo apt-get install lightdm`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Should get the expected outcome by using `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Then after installing you can install a lightweight display manager using LightDM

1. `sudo apt install lightdm`
2. Select option `lightdm` then press ok

Tested using UTM 3.2.4, Ubuntu 22.04

---

Note: `apt-get` is normally used for older versions of linux < 16.0, use `apt` when working with modern instances unless you need backwards capability of certain scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The base operating system you chose probably does not support the `ubuntu-desktop` profile in `tasksel`. You can see what things *are* available to install by running:

```
tasksel --list
```

More information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel (task definitions are in the `/usr/share/tasksel` directory as `*.desc` files).

I am myself trying to determine why `ubuntu-tasks.desc` is not available on a machine using an Ubuntu 2022 base disk image.

P.S. -- You might have more luck with Ubuntu-specific questions at https://askubuntu.com/